# Confused about flexbox/Angular Material Grid

Tags: css, flexbox, angular-material

So I'm trying to get this sort of layout using Angular Material Grid (based on flexbox)

[image]

Here's my code now  (the width is width of parent full screen, and height is 700 just to mockup the layout)

```
<div class="mid-section">
 <div layout="row" style="width:100%; height:700px;">
  <!-- Left-hand side -->
  <div layout="column" flex="70">
    <md-card flex="70">
      Box 1
    </md-card>
    <md-card flex="30">
      Box 2
    </md-card>
  </div>
  <div layout="column" flex="30">
    <md-card flex="30">
      Box 3
    </md-card>
    <md-card flex="70">
      Box 4
    </md-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

All I'm getting it to do is this - 
[image]

Comment: What is the output CSS?

Comment: .layout-column > .flex-30, .layout-column > .flex-30 {
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 30%;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 30%;
    flex: 1 1 30%;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 30%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to comment with just the raw Angular / Material code rather than the *actual* HTML/CSS...but it should be something like this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
}
.column div {
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
}
.column {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flex70 {
  flex: 7;
}
.flex30 {
  flex: 3
}
```

```html
<div class="mid-section">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column flex70">
      <div class="flex70">Box 1
      </div>
      <div class="flex30">Box 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column flex30">
      <div class="flex30">
        Box 3
      </div>
      <div class="flex70">
        Box 4
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```